# PostgreSQL SELECT WHERE IN Subquery with its own condition from other column

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a (temporary) table (let's just call it param) with records like shown below

```
BranchID |       DateFrom      |       DateTo
   154   | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-01-01 23:59:59
   361   | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 2019-01-01 23:59:59
   362   | 2019-01-01 10:00:00 | 2019-01-02 09:59:59
```

now if I want to select all of transactions that is done by those branches i can do like

```
SELECT *
FROM "Transaction" t
WHERE t."BranchID" IN (SELECT "BranchID" FROM param)
```

but i want my select to be restricted only for those datefrom and dateto. if however the datefrom and dateto is universal for every branch we can do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM "Transaction" t
WHERE t."BranchID" IN (SELECT "BranchID" FROM param)
AND t."TransactionDate" >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
AND t."TransactionDate" <= '2019-01-01 23:59:59'::TIMESTAMP
```

but the problem is each branch has their own end of days (like shown in table `param`). is it possible to do it in one query like above? if possible i dont want to process it in php like doing foreach from table param and do the query for transaction for each row (branch) because that'll increase execution time (especially when we have more than 100 branches) so I want to make 1 big select for all branches and then I grouping it using PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT t.*
 FROM "Transaction" t JOIN param p 
 ON p."BranchID" = t."BranchID"
AND t."TransactionDate" >= p.DateFrom
AND t."TransactionDate" <= p.DateTo
```

An `EXISTS` should also work fine.

```
SELECT t.*
     FROM "Transaction" t WHERE EXISTS 
( SELECT 1 FROM param p 
     WHERE p."BranchID" = t."BranchID"
    AND t."TransactionDate" >= p.DateFrom
    AND t."TransactionDate" <= p.DateTo
)
```